# How to conditionally compile classes based on deployment profile?

Tags: java, netbeans

In [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) there is a code command available to conditionally compile the code. [.Net Directive Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if).

Is there an equivalent in [java](/questions/tagged/java) or [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) to achieve this same approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one included by default in the compiler, but maybe [the preprocessor capabilities of Manifold](https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/tree/master/manifold-deps-parent/manifold-preprocessor) could help in your case. It supports the usual `#define`, `#undef`, `#if` *et al.* available in C and its cousins.

Comment: Sweet....doesn't have the DEBUG auto variable but i can work with that and #DEFINE :)